# How to validate that two operators arn't being put after each other. Calculator Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made a simple calculator using the usual HTML, CSS, Javascript and have run into a problem.

when I was validating the user input , Right now the calculator takes in multiple operators after each other.

I tried to disable this by checking the screen.innerHTML for any operators before ad and if one was found to output an alert that told them that is invalid input.

Here is my code that you will hopefully understand better:

**=> HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<title>Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="main-div">
    <div class="screen" id="screen"><p></p></div>
        <div class="clear" id="clear">C</div>
            <ul class="number-div">
                 <li>1</li>
                 <li>2</li>
                 <li>3</li>
                 <li>+</li>
                 <li>4</li>
                 <li>5</li>
                 <li>6</li>
                 <li>*</li>
                 <li>7</li>
                 <li>8</li>
                 <li>9</li>
                 <li>-</li>
                 <li>0</li>
                 <li id="blank"></li>
                 <li id="equals">=</li>
                 <li>/</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

**=> Javascript:**

```
window.onload = function (){
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var screen = document.querySelectorAll('p')[0];   // Returns a static NodeList of all elements descended from the element which it was invoked from that matches the specified group of CSS selectors
var clear = document.getElementsByClassName('clear')[0];

for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
      if(elements[i].innerHTML === '='){
            elements[i].addEventListener("click", calculate(i));
      }else{
           elements[i].addEventListener("click", addtocurrentvalue(i));
      }
}

function addtocurrentvalue (i){
return function(){
    if (screen.innerHTML == "*" || screen.innerHTML=="+" || screen.innerHTML=="/" || screen.innerHTML=="-" && elements[i].innerHTML == "*" || elements[i].innerHTML=="+" || elements[i].innerHTML=="/" || elements[i].innerHTML=="-")  { 
       alert("Please enter number and then operator!");
    }else {
       screen.innerHTML += elements[i].innerHTML;

function calculate(i) {
return function () {
    if(screen.innerHTML ==''){
        alert("Please Enter valid Inputs");
    }else {
        screen.innerHTML = eval(screen.innerHTML);
    }


};
```

}

Comment: pls share executable snippet or fiddler. your code not at all working!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a var what contain last button clicked and validate to know if is a operator.

```
var lastClicked;
```

And when clicked:

```
function clicked(item){
    if (lastClicked != undefined && (lastClicked.value == "*" || lastClicked.value=="+" || lastClicked.value=="/" || lastClicked.value=="-")){
        alert('Last Button Clicked : ' + lastClicked.value)
    }
    lastClicked = item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `let` instead `var` here `var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)`.
But read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) at first.`Let` is a new feature and it may not be supported by old browsers.
Also, you could find some information here https://javascript.info/task/make-army
It will help you to understand this issue better.